# Some buildings don't appear in 3d using mapbox gl js, how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, 3d, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to adopt this [Display buildings in 3D](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/3d-buildings/) example, but I found out that in my city (Minsk, Belarus) some buildings look flat like this:

[image: flat building]

The coordinates of this particular building are 27.552516, 53.897726 (lon, lat).

I checked out the attributes os this building in OSM and didn't find any special:

[image: OSM attributes]

There is only a number of floors as data about height, but it's the same for the rest of buildings which appear volumetric.

I haven't changed the code yet so I don't leave it here coz it's in the Mapbox example above. Could someone tells me how to fix that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like for some reason the `extrude` property for this building is equal to `false`. Try changing the filter for the layer with the extrude of buildings:

```
'filter': ['==', 'extrude', 'true']

// =>

'filter': ['>', 'height', 0]
```